# Access denied when trying to upload audio files to aws s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload audio files to a folder in my s3 bucket. I'm doing this by dragging and dropping from my laptop and hitting the upload button once I have dropped the last file. Some of the files failed to upload and instead gave me an error message saying

```
Access Denied. You don't have permissions to upload files and folders.
```

How do I fix that?

Comment: Do you have permissions to upload? have u written any bucket policy , role permission?

Comment: What do you mean by "some of the files failed to upload"? Are you saying that some of them _did_ upload? Does it still succeed if you upload the successful ones again (to check that nothing has changed)? Please edit your question to show _how_ you are uploading the files and exactly where/how that error message was provided. You'll need to give us _much_ more information to be able to assist you.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Frank Din's answer, I was able to upload a folder's 80+ images at once by selecting "Add Folder" instead of drag-and-dropping all the images at once.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was eventually able to upload all the audio files.

I think the problem in my case was that I was trying to upload all the files practically at the same time by just dragging and dropping them all in the same breath.

I fixed that by uploading each file one at a time and only after the previous file was done uploading.